# my java-server back-end code needs deployment in cloud

Tags: java, ios, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have made an IOS App using the IOS-native, and I have written the server code in the Java code and I want to deploy the server code in the Cloud.

I don't want to deploy the IOS-native app, and I just want to deploy the server back-end Java Code.

Please illustrate the solution briefly,

Thanks. :D

Comment: Have you read any guides? Try https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-webapp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Manthan Welcome to StackOverflow. You can use three ways to host your Java Application on Azure:

1. Create an Azure VM and host your app:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/install-java-application-server-in-virtual-machine/

2. Create a Java app on Azure App Service on Windows

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-java

3. Create an Azure function to host your Java code:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-azurefunctions

Hope this helps!